# Mongoose - Add 'is_self' field in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm building a chat app, that should retrieve all new messages from MongoDB, grouped in to conversations. But each message should have a new 'is_self' field

Edit:
The 'is_self' field contains a boolean for if the message if from the user.

so pseudo:

```
is_self: {$cond: {if: {message.sender == MYID)}, then: true, else: false}
```

So lets say I have Message model

```
    var MessageSchema  = new Schema({
    conversation_id:{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Conversation', required: true},
    message: {type: String, required: true},
    sender: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    read: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

And a Conversation model

```
    var ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    from: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    to: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    last_changed: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Now I try to do an Aggregate, to load all messages that are inside a conversation_id array and are created > last_checked date...

So it looks like this:

```
mongoose.model("Message").aggregate([
            // First find all messages
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [{conversation_id: {$in: idArray}}, {created: {$gt: lastChecked}}]
                }
            },
            // Add is self field
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: $_id,
                    $is_self: {
                        $cond: {'if(message.sender == MYID then true else false': '??'}
                    }
                }
            },
            // Sort by date
            {$sort: {created: -1}},

            // Then group by conversation
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$conversation_id',
                    messages: {
                        $push: '$$ROOT'
                    },

                }
            }
            // TODO: find users for unknown conversation
            /*,
            {
                $project: {
                    user: {
                        $or: [{conversation_id: {$in: knownConversations}}]
                    }
                }
            }*/
        ])
```

I tried with $cond and if / else statement but Mongo doesn't allow that..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple usage of the [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) operator which returns boolean. Also [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) will take any object format you throw at it:

```
var senderId = // whatever;

mongooose.model("Message").aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "conversation_id": { "$in": idArray },
        "created": { "$gt": lastChecked }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$conversation_id",
        "messages": {
            "$push": {
                "message": "$message",
                "is_self": { 
                    "$eq": [ "$sender", senderId ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
    // whatever else
],function(err,results) {

})
```

If you want, then combine with [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to alternately add "is_self" only when detected:

```
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$conversation_id",
        "messages": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$sender", senderId] },
                  {
                    "message": "$message",
                    "is_self": true
                  },
                  {
                     "messsage": "$message" 
                  }
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: You nailed it! I  didn't realise $push can be used in such a way. This also saves for using $group 2 times. Thank you

Comment: @DutchKev You might also note that you are overusing `$and`. All query arguments are implicitly an `$and` expression ( unless purposefully stated otherwise ), so you make your life a lot easier by being aware of that. Less typing and all of that. Moreover `$$ROOT` does not do what you seem to think. It is just a placeholder variable for the "current" document in the pipeline stage. You seem to think it means the "original" document state. But it does not mean that.

Comment: Less typing is always good! Thanks. I indeed found out that I misjudged $$ROOT. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @DutchKev I have never liked the naming and personally find it misleading. Ther is also `$$CURRENT` which is the same thing, and documentation is "errm" ambiguous to the distiction between the two or what the distinction even means. Not the first to be mislead. By your commented out section of code, you might have another question coming up. But take a look at what you have learned first and try some things.

Comment: you are 1 step ahead of me :p Indeed I also have struggles with the population of users within the pipeline (the commented part)..  But my good 'sunday' guts tells me that I can fix that problem by partially implementing the same structure as given in your excellent answer.. I will figure it out, thanks